# log-likelihood ratio test question

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Just a quick question

When performing a log-likelihood ratio test, do I take log to both of the likelihood first or find the ratio first and take the log?

Answer (score 0):

The test is actually a '[likelihood ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test)'. This ratio is often called $\Lambda$ (Lambda).

If you're using [Wilks' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) to obtain the asymptotic chi-square distribution of $-2\log\Lambda$, then you take the log of the ratio (or equivalently, the *difference* of the logs of the numerator and denominator), and multiply by $-2$ (giving a non-negative number, if you've done it right). So there's a reason to consider the log of the likelihood ratio.

Comment: yes I know that but the question is asking me log-likelihood ratio that makes me confused

Comment: You're asking about two possible interpretations of the phrase "log-likelihood ratio". My post explains that there's only one interpretation that really makes sense (there's a good reason to take a ratio of likelihoods, because a *likelihood ratio* is a meaningful quantity, and is used, for solid reasons, for hypothesis tests. A test can be based on the log of that (and, multiplying by -2, has a standard, widely tabulated distribution). There's no corresponding reason to look at the other interpretation - what possible value is there is taking a ratio of log-likelihoods? So why the confusion?

Comment: @natsu `log-likelihood ratio` is a standard typographical usage that is not supposed to be interpreted literally as you are doing. It _should_ be written as `log(likelihood-ratio)` thus making it clear that just as $\log(x)$ means the logarithm of $x$, what is wanted is the logarithm of the likelihood ratio. Unfortunately, the incorrect form `log-likelihood ratio` has been used so often in the past that it will be difficult to get rid of it entirely. Nowadays, people don't interpret it literally; they just mentally translate into `log(likelihood ratio)`.